# How to Click on an webelement, if it is not a paid content? - Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a video link from a streaming site.

The problem is that some of the video contents from the site may be pay-to-view content with a text saying "Exclusive" on the upper corner of the content. This is random and I am not sure how to check whether the content is free and click on it.

Here is DOM:

[image: screenshot]

It will be very helpful if someone sort me out on this.

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. Instead post the code/errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Above dom is for which section? Which element on the video you want to click ? And which section (in terms of HTML DOM)  is containing **Exclusive** text for paid contents ? Also can you please share what you have tried till now.

Comment: I am trying to click on the video thumbnail . Above dom is for the whole vidoe thumbnail section. On the image , if you notice, then you can see that the div class :slick-slide slick-active contains the whole video thumbnail portion. The highlighted span class contains the text "Exclusive". Some of the videos has this "Exclusive " text. This is random. I just need to know how should I distinguish between free and pay-to view content. and click on just the free video.